# Error while fetching data from MySQL to Android in java (error while converting string to jsonArray)

Tags: android, android-studio

This try block is not executing instead catch block is executing. Not able to find any error. I want to convert the string into a `JSON array`. In the LogCat I can see the data is coming from the MySQL database but after that `catch` block is executing and showing `error fetching the data.  **[See the NOTE after the code]**

**Main Code**

```
 public void getJSON(final String urlWebService){
        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                Log.d("Check","doInBackground start");
                URL url = null;
                try {
                    url = new URL(urlWebService);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String json;
                    while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(json).append("\n");
                    }
                  return sb.toString().trim();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("Check","doInBackground end");
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                Log.d("Check","onPostExecute start");
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                s=s.replace("success","");
                Log.d("Check",s);
                try{
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.d("Check", "onPostExecute: "+obj.getString("name"));
                    }

                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("Check","error while fatching data");
                }
                Log.d("Check","onPostExecute end");
            }
        }
        GetJSON getJSON = new GetJSON();
        getJSON.execute();
    }
```

**Error in code**

```
try{
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            Log.d("Check", "onPostExecute: "+obj.getString("name"));
                        }
    
                    } catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("Check","error while fatching data");
                    }
```

**output in Logcat:--**

2021-03-26 23:20:31.995 5241-5241/com.game.samplecollection D/Check:onPostExecute start

2021-03-26 23:20:32.000 5241-5241/com.game.samplecollection D/Check: [{"id":"50","name":"mk","image":"http://localhost/sampleImages/mk.png","city":"agartala","state":"Karnataka","monsoon":"Pre Monsoon","sampleType":"Soil","latLon":"(37.4219983 , -122.084)","ph":"f","ec":"ftds=f","tds":"","arsenic":"f","nitrate":"f","fluoride":"f","sulphate":"f","chloride":"f","hardness":"f","alkalinity":"f"},{"id":"49","name":"A1","image":"http://localhost/sampleImages/A1.png","city":"Agartala","state":"Tripura","monsoon":"Post Monsoon","sampleType":"Water","latLon":"(23.856107 , 91.2867835)","ph":"7.6","ec":"8.4tds=4","tds":"","arsenic":"3","nitrate":"6","fluoride":"9","sulphate":"1","chloride":"2","hardness":"5","alkalinity":"9"},{"id":"43","name":"a1","image":"http://localhost/sampleImages/a1.png","city":"agartala","state":"Tripura","monsoon":"Pre Monsoon","sampleType":"Water","latLon":"(23.8562057 , 91.2893458)","ph":"1.6","ec":"5.9tds=6.8","tds":"","arsenic":"4.7","nitrate":"9.8","fluoride":"65","sulphate":"5","chloride":"6","hardness":"4","alkalinity":"4"},{"id":"48","name":"n2`","image":"http:\/\/localhost\/sampleImages\/n2`.png","city":"agarala","state":"Goa","monsoon":"Pre Monsoon","sampleType":"Soil","latLon":"(37.4219983 , -122.084)","ph":"1.2","ec":"5.3tds=5.62","tds":"","arsenic":"2.3","nitrate":"21.2","fluoride":"..2","sulphate":"5.","chloride":".","hardness":"23.","alkalinity":"220"},{"id":"47","name":"A1","image":"http://localhost/sampleImages/A1.png","city":"Agartala","state":"Tripura","monsoon":"Post Monsoon","sampleType":"Water","latLon":"(23.856107 , 91.2867835)","ph":"7.6","ec":"8.4tds=4","tds":"","arsenic":"3","nitrate":"6","fluoride":"9","sulphate":"1","chloride":"2","hardness":"5","alkalinity":"9"},{"id":"45","name":"A1","image":"http://localhost/sampleImages/A1.png","city":"Agartala","state":"Tripura","monsoon":"Post Monsoon","sampleType":"Water","latLon":"(23.856107 , 91.2867835)","ph":"7.6","ec":"8.4tds=4","tds":"","arsenic":"3","nitrate":"6","fluoride":"9","sulphate":"1","chloride":"2","hardness":"5","alkalinity":"9"},{"id":"46","name":"A1","image":"http://localhost/sampleImages/A1.png","city":"Agartala","state":"Tripura","monsoon":"Post Monsoon","sampleType":"Water","latLon":"(23.856107 , 91.2867835)","ph":"7.6","ec":"8.4tds=4","tds":"","arsenic":"3","nitrate":"6","fluoride":"9","sulphate":"1","chloride":"2","hardness":"5","alkalinity":"9"},{"id":"44","name":"A1","image":"http://localhost/sampleImages/A1.png","city":"Agartala","state":"Tripura","monsoon":"Post Monsoon","sampleType":"Water","latLon":"(23.856107 , 91.2867835)","ph":"7.6","ec":"8.4tds=4","tds":"","arsenic":"3","nitrate":"6","fluoride":"9","sulphate":"1","chloride":"2","hardness":"5","alkalinity":"9"},{"id":"51","name":"2","image":"http://localhost/sampleImages/2.png","city":"agartala","state":"Daman and Diu","monsoon":"Pre Monsoon","sampleType":"Soil","latLon":"(37.4219983 , -122.084)","ph":"4","ec":"5tds=6","tds":"","arsenic":"9","nitrate":"4","fluoride":"8","sulphate":"7","chloride":"5","hardness":"2","alkalinity":"3"},{"id":"52","name":"2","image":"http://localhost/sampleImages/2.png","city":"agartala","state":"Daman and Diu","monsoon":"Pre Monsoon","sampleType":"Soil","latLon":"(37.4219983 , -122.084)","ph":"4","ec":"5tds=6","tds":"","arsenic":"9","nitrate":"4","fluoride":"8","sulphate":"7","chloride":"5","hardness":"2","alkalinity":"3"},{"id":"53","name":"2","image":"http://localhost/sampleImages/2.png","city":"agartala","state":"Daman and Diu","monsoon":"Pre Monsoon","sampleType":"Soil","latLon":"(37.4219983 , -122.084)","ph":"4","ec":"5tds=6","tds":"","arsenic":"9","nitrate":"4","fluoride":"8","sulphate":"7","chloride":"5","hardness":"2","alkalinity":"3"},{"id":"54","name":"2","image":"http://localhost/sampleImages/2.png","city":"agartala","state":"Daman and Diu","monsoon":"Pre Monsoon","sampleType":"Soil","latLon":"(37.4219983 , -122.084)","ph":"4","ec":"5tds=6","tds":"","arsenic":"9","nitrate":"4","fluoride":"8","sulphate":"7","chloride":"5","hardness":"2","alkalinity":"3"},{"id":"55","name":"2","image":"http://localhost\

**2021-03-26 23:20:32.088 5241-5241/com.game.samplecollection D/Check: error while fatching data**

2021-03-26 23:20:32.088 5241-5241/com.game.samplecollection D/Check: onPostExecute end

**NOTE**
I can see all the data from MySQL database are fetched in LogCat but not able to convert it to JSON Array.

Comment: `Log.d("Check",s)` what is this statement prints in log

Comment: Witch exception is caught by the catch block?

Comment: Check the above details. I edited and provided the full details of the code and output in LogCat. Hope you can help me out with this.